# google drive sdk quickstart python sample error

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm following the sample python code for the quickstart page of Google Drive SDK (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart#set_up_the_sample) and get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 45, in <module>
    file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/apiclient/http.py", line 656, in execute
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/apiclient/http.py", line 733, in next_chunk
apiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: Failed to retrieve starting URI.
```

after entering the verification code.  The steps are fairly straight forward so I'm wondering if the sample code is out of date (although I haven't seen other people running into this error so it seems it might be something related to my setup, but I'm not sure what that would be).  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does the code run on a different machine? as a different user? in a clean virtualenv? Possibly a network error, so double-check firewalls, proxy settings, blacklists, etc.

Comment: Sample code is accurate, I just tried it today. You could check you have an up-to-date library installed?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on papahoolio's answer:

You need to make sure the service is enabled, **but there's a gotcha**: There's both a "Drive SDK" **and** a "Drive API" service, and only the latter ("Drive API") will work. However, the former has the nice Drive icon, and if you're like me, you tunnel-visioned it.

To enable:

- Go to https://code.google.com/apis/console
- Click Services on the menu on the left.
- Enable "**Drive API**" (*not* Drive SDK, though you can enable that too if you want).

Answer (score 0):

In the Google API console there are two services relating to drive development, SDK and API. Make sure Drive **API** is on

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the corporate version of Google Drive. When running against the non-business Google Drive, the sample code worked fine. The oauth was being blocked by corporate policies.